# Error printing endlessly: KeyError: 'matplotlib.pyplot'

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, pycharm

I was creating word clouds in python, and used the following code:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import numpy as np
from wordcloud import WordCloud
mpl.use('TkAgg')
mpl = mpl.reload(mpl)
```

When I run pycharm now and load a pandas dataframe. If I even start typing df.shape, my console begins endlessly printing the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Applications/PyCharm 
CE.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/pydevconsole.py", line 207, in 
process_exec_queue
inputhook()
File "/Applications/PyCharm 
CE.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/pydev_ipython/inputhook.py", line 428, 
in inputhook_mac
pyplot = sys.modules['matplotlib.pyplot']
KeyError: 'matplotlib.pyplot'
```

The error never stops printing.

I can stop this from occurring if I run this code when I start pycharm:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('agg')
matplotlib = matplotlib.reload(matplotlib)
```

Obviously this is not something I want to run everytime I start pycharm. 
Python 3.5.2
Matplotlib 2.0.2

Any suggestions?

Comment: It's not clear from the question if this is only occuring if `wordcloud` is imported. What happens if you leave that out?

Comment: If I restart pycharm and don't work with wordcloud at all, I still get this issue. I can just open pycharm, load a dataset, and then type data.shape() and the error occurs.

Comment: In my case, I set a breakpoint in a multiprocessing code in PyCharm and the error appeared. The error is fixed after I move the breakpoint (or set it at a single thread line). This problem seems to be related to multithreading. See disscuss [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python/issues/2982#issuecomment-433692689)

Answer (score 0):

I do not know the cause of the problem, but it you are happy with your solution, you can put this configuration into the matplotlib configuration file, as is described here: https://matplotlib.org/users/customizing.html#the-matplotlibrc-file and it will be loaded automatically.